# change object with angular foreach loop to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my object
    {angry: "ok", sad: "nw", fire: "ok", happy: "nw","something":"good"}

I want to change this object to something like this:

```
val[nw][0]="sad"
val[nw][1]="happy"
val[ok][0]="angry"
val[ok][1]="fire"
val[good][0]="something"
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and build a new object upon.

```js
var object = { angry: "ok", sad: "nw", fire: "ok", happy: "nw", something: "good" },
    result = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    result[object[k]] = result[object[k]] || [];
    result[object[k]].push(k);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```